# Create executable to run a shortcut? Similar to a .bat file but a .exe?

Tags: windows

I have a keyboard with 6 keys I can assign pretty much anything to, including opening apps.

I want to be able to open Spotify with one of these keys, but I have to have to link a .exe to to the key - no other file type will work.

I have Spotify downloaded from the Windows Store, so it's stuck under the WindowsApp folder in Program Files, which means I can't access it directly. Even if I create a shortcut and put it on the desktop, it's not an .exe, it a .lnk.

I'm wondering if there's a way to create a .exe file that will run the Spotify shortcut that I have on my desktop, or any app at all.

I know it sounds redundant - creating a .exe to run a .exe - but I can't access the WindowsApp folder to directly link it to my keyboard. I know a batch file would work, but I can't link a .bat to my keyboard, only .exe.

I don't have experience creating executables, so I don't even know where to start and I haven't been able to find anything online.

Comment: Are you trying to say that all you need is just an exe file that runs another program? Because if so, it is very easy to do so.

Answer (score 4):

If you wish to try this yourself, you will need to:

- install a compiler
- write the code
- use the compiler to create an executable

While this might sound complicated for somebody without experience, in this case is not that hard.

---

Here is how you can do it using the very simple ***`PureBasic compiler`***:

- download and install the PureBasic compiler from this website

  - https://www.purebasic.com/download.php
  - (the demo version is fine, it will do the job)
  - choose [PureBasic-Demo.zip (x64 - 64 bit)]

---

- launch the PureBasic IDE and write this code:

  - in this example I'm making an executable which will launch Sublime Text, so change the path to your Spotify executable

```

```
; // make this a console program
OpenConsole()

; // specify path to another executable
pathToExecutable$ = "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe"

; // use RunProgram to launch another executable
x = RunProgram(pathToExecutable$)
```

```

---

- after you enter the code, click on `File` menu at the top, then click on `Save As...`, you will be prompted for ***a name for your source code file***.
- select a location, for example your `Desktop` then, enter a name for the file, for example `proxy`. (this will create a `proxy.pb` file)

---

- last step, create the `proxy.exe` executable
- click on `Compiler` menu, then click on `Create Executable...`
- select location (again I recommend your Desktop), then ***enter a name for the executable***, again for example `proxy` and then click on `Save` (this will create `proxy.exe` on your Desktop)

---

You can move your new created executable anywhere, it's portable.

Good luck!

Comment: This sounds like just what I need. However I have a question... instead of  defining the file location, I want open an exe found in the same folder, regardless of where they are installed. What code would you recommend for that?

Comment: Ok, found GetCurrentDirectory() and using it like GetCurrentDirectory() + new.exe. Works like a gem and only 7Kb for the exe.

Answer (score -1):

This is Stack Overflow where you can do it yourself so here is how.

1. Download a BAT to EXE convertor from [here](http://www.f2ko.de/en/b2e.php) or [here](http://www.bat2exe.net/).
2. Make a batch file to start the program of your choice. (Code would look like the following)
   `@start "" "C:\users\JimithyJones\Desktop\Spotify.exe" && exit`
3. Convert it to an EXE with one of the previous programs. WARNING! Sometimes they are detected as malicious files because batch files have the capability to do harm to your computor.
4. Assign the new EXE to your hotkeys.

Comment: I wouldn't bother with this. While it looks like it SHOULD work (and technically it does) it will just get detected as a virus by pretty much every single anti-virus (including Windows defender) and automatically deleted.